# Array reference and implicit constructor: bug in gcc or not?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, c++14, compiler-bug

The following code [compiles fine with *clang 3.5.0*, but doesn't compile with *gcc 4.9.0*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d871a1bcac885dc) (with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` flags and with any of `-std=c++03`, `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14` flags):

```
struct S
{
    S(const float(&)[12])
    {
    }
};

float v[12];

S f()
{
    return v;
}

int main()
{
}
```

*MS VC 2013* [compiles this code fine](http://rextester.com/IAM92603), too.

Which compiler is right and what is standard-compliant behavior?

Comment: Looks like `GCC` is interpreting `float v[12];` as a function, which is weird. If you don't find a solution here, try reporting it on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Comment: [using {}s](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a745e775eea287f9) is a workaround (C++11).  `return {blah};` directly constructs the return value in C++11, which seems to bypass whatever code converts `v` to a pointer prior to trying to construct the return value of `f`.  This does make me wonder about the semantics of `auto f() { return v; }` in C++14 and `decltype(auto) f() { return v; }`

Comment: @matsjoyce : the other question is about a specific case of this bug (namely for character arrays), where the behavior is indeed slightly different from what the OP observes. It is the same bug though - check the link to several bug reports in the accepted answer (eg. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16333).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker In that case, its a shame its not been fixed yet (10 years...)

Comment: 16333 looks like it, I agree with matsjoyce anyway :/ There's no decaying involved, it seems that gcc is too fast at doing it

Comment: @Yakk Thank you. Unfortunately, C++14 is not suitable for me. Another workaround is simply to call a constructor explicitly: `S f(){return S(v);}`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker 10 years! It is unbelievable! This code looks so simply... Thank you for your reference.

Comment: You don't need C++14 -- that was an aside at the end of the comment.  C++11 is enough with `return {S}`, which also avoids calling the move/copy constructor of `S` (admittedly, that is almost always elided).

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I understand it. My comment was only about your workarounds which use `auto` / `decltype(auto)`. And yes, I know about copy/move elision, thank you.

Comment: Those where not workarounds.  I was just publicly wondering what the C++ standard said about what the type of `auto f() { return v; }` and `decltype(auto) f() { return v; }` where `v` is a C style array:  I'm guessing the first returns a pointer.  The second, I could not venture a reasonable guess.

Comment: @Yakk I see now. It is interesting. Yes, simple `auto` should be deduced to a pointer as I know. But `decltype(auto)`... Both [*clang* and *gcc* generate errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fb55519d506172a) but they are very strange.